# Click a button to highlight a field

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-word, excel-2010, acrobat

I'm working with a company document that was created in Word.  The form was never intended to be filled out digitally but instead to be printed and filled out by hand.  There are 5 check boxes across the top followed by 9 different sections of the form.  Some of the sections need to be filled out regardless of what is checked at the top; others are conditional depending on what has been checked at the top.

My goal is to digitize this in a way so that all the required fields are highlighted.  So if I click the 3rd button up top sections 3 and 4 get highlighted.  If I click the 1st button section 2 gets highlighted.  If I click the first and 3rd buttons then sections 2, 3, and 4 get highlighted.

Unfortunately it's a controlled document so I can't post it here but hopefully that gives you an idea.

I have Microsoft Office (2010), Adobe Acrobat, and GIMP at my disposal.  I'm not against writing VBA or JavaScript to make this happen but I've never gotten as far as Hello World in either.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you have to offer!

Comment: This is a very broad request, and missing key information to give a targeted answer... For one thing, there's the question about what kind of "controls" to use. Does this need protecting as a form or should it be freely editable (and formattable)?

Comment: Things like that can be set up in Excel. Highlighting of form parts can be done with conditional formatting. Check boxes can be done several ways. If needed, VBA can serve to round things off. This is way too complex for a single question here, though. In any case you would need to make a start and post your efforts here if you get stuck. Then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with the answer, but this can easily be done with Acrobat.

The easiest way is to look at the field naming, and use hierarchical field names, which allow you to group fields by name. In the present case, we would have something like `sect.4.myField`, where the number corresponds to the section the field belongs to.

Now, for highlighting, we can define any color using the color Object in (Acrobat) JavaScript; for simplicity's sake, I am going to use a pre-defined color, yellow (which is too strong for practical use, but OK for showing how it works). In the case of section 4, you'd add the following to the mouseUp event of the checkbox for section 4:

```
if (event.target.value == "4") {
this.getField("sect.4").fillColor = color.yellow ;
} else {
this.getField("sect.4").fillColor = color.transparent ; 
// could also be color.white
}
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to highlight sections of a PDF document based on “checkbox” selections using JavaScript™ and the Acrobat®/JavaScript API. For example, Figure 1 ([for the PDF version of this reply](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/Reply$1454047113.pdf)) is an example of a form where sections are highlighted based on “checkbox” selections.

[image]

Here are some ideas to consider when creating PDF forms with special process logic (e.g. highlights):

1. Learn how to use Adobe® Acrobat – especially how to create and to use form elements such as buttons (Adobe, 2012a).
2. Learn how to program in JavaScript with the Acrobat/JavaScript API (Adobe, 2012b; 2012c; Flanagan, 2006).

   a.    Furthermore, you might have to learn how to “map” your process logic or algorithm and use the “map” to guide you in writing the computer codes. For the highlight process logic of Figure 1, I created a “map” of the process logic before writing the computer codes for the logic (Chionglo, 2014; 2016), and then I created the form in Figure 1.
3. Learn how to convert your print form into a PDF document.

   a.    Learn how to create PDF from Word™.

   b.    Learn how to scan a document and to convert the scanned image into a PDF document.

   ```
   i.  In case you have the print form only.
   ```
4. Learn how to use PowerPoint® (or other vector-based or raster-based graphics software that can export to PDF) to create custom graphics for highlighting sections (Microsoft®, 2013).

   a.    As Max Wyss suggested, it is possible to modify the fill color of a field (such as a button) to represent the highlight (“Click”, 2016). However you might need special graphics for the highlights; in this case, you can set the special graphics as icons of buttons for the highlights.

### References

Adobe Systems Incorporated. (2012a). Adobe Acrobat XI [software]. San Jose, California: Adobe Systems Incorporated.

Adobe Systems Incorporated. (2012b). Adobe Acrobat X SDK Developing Acrobat Applications Using JavaScript for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS [electronic version]. Edition 1.0, October 2012. San Jose, California: Adobe Systems Incorporated.

Adobe Systems Incorporated. (2012c). Adobe Acrobat X SDK JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference for Microsoft Windows and Mac OS [electronic version]. Edition 1.0, October 2012. San Jose, California: Adobe Systems Incorporated.
Chionglo, J. F. (2016). Highlight Section Process: A Petri Net Model. Available at http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/1453977648.pdf.

Chionglo, J. F. (2014). 1.  Net Elements and Annotations for Computer Programming: Computations and Interactions in PDF. Available at http://www.aespen.ca/NetElementsAndAnnotationsForComputerProgramming.pdf.

“Click a Button to Highlight a Field” (2016). Stack Overflow. Retrieved on Dec. 14, 2015 at [Click a button to highlight a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373099/click-a-button-to-highlight-a-field).

Flanagan, D. (2006). JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, Fifth Edition. Sebastopol, CA: O’Reilly Media Inc.

Microsoft (2013). PowerPoint 2013 [software]. Redmond, WA: Microsoft Corporation.